# Angular 2 - Any way to determine line that error is on?

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors

I am building an app on Angular 2 and whenever I get an error I have no idea where to go because the Angular 2 errors are very poor and don't even tell me what file to look in.  Is there anything that I could use to map out where my error is coming from in my TS files?

Thanks

Comment: are you using the cmd prompt or the dev console in browser? both contain error output. you will typically only get line numbers during syntax errors. otherwise, the error outputted will generally tell you what file is failing. it takes a little bit to get used to the angular errors, if you are struggling with a specific one, just post it up.

Comment: Normally Angular tells you WHAT is wrong and in WHICH component..

Comment: @Bean0341thanks, using the dev console in chrome